# How to create a simple FirstPersonController in Unity: Compiler ERROR messages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, game-physics

I'm extremely new to Unity and coding so I'm an absolute beginner. I'm attempting to create my own "FirstPersonController" from scratch whilst following tutorials. However, most of the tutorials provide the code but it doesn't work when I use it in my Unity scripts, I continiously see errors.

I'll provide the error messages and the code that I've written and hopefully someone can help as I have no idea what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

ERROR MESSAGES

1) Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(3,14): error CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'PlayerController'

2) Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(14,10): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerController' already defines a member called 'Awake' with the same parameter types

3) Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(19,10): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerController' already defines a member called 'Update' with the same parameter types

4) Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(30,10): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerController' already defines a member called 'FixedUpdate' with the same parameter types

5) Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(39,10): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerController' already defines a member called 'Move' with the same parameter types

CODE/ C# SCRIPT

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Public Variables

    public float walkspeed;

    //Private Variables

    Rigidbody rb;
    Vector3 moveDirection;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Non-Physics steps
        //Get directional input from the user

        float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = (horizontalMovement * transform.right + verticalMovement * transform.forward).normalized;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Physics steps
        //Call the Move function

        Move();

    }

    void Move()
    {
        //Here we define the move funtion
        //Rigid.velocity is a method which takes a Vector3 and controls the speed and direction of the GameObject

        rb.velocity = moveDirection * walkspeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough beginning something like C# with Unity, but with hardwork, you can prevail. At the very start of your code `public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour`, there is probably another script already named `PlayerController` somewhere in your assets folder. So there are two classes essentially. Try searching in Unity to see if there are two scripts. See which one you need to remove. Let me know if this helps you please.